# React Native Expo Buttons stopped working

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm facing a really weird issue in my expo react native app. I've implemented some basic login and registration screens using my custom modal. Everything was working fine, except when I installed following libraries :

BEFORE THE ISSUE :

```
yarn add styled-components

yarn add react-native-paper
yarn add react-native-safe-area-context
yarn add react-native-vector-icons

yarn add @react-navigation/stack  
npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler

npx expo install firebase                             
npx expo install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

npx expo install expo-image
```

AFTER THE ISSUE :

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native 
yarn add @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs 
yarn add react-native-vector-icons 
npx expo install react-native-screens 
npx expo install react-native-safe-area-context 
npx expo install expo-system-ui
```

I tried to implement theming by installing those libraries, and after I logged out of the app, tried to login again, nothing was reacting to pressing. After clicking on any button/touchableOpacity, no response, not even console.log works.

So initially, I reverted to commit before the newly installed libs, and then installed them on by one trying to solve the mystery which one is causing this weird behaviour, but with no success.. I installed all of them in the same order as before, but app was behaving fine.. So I just continued without further investigation.

Then the next day the same issue occurred again..
I'm totally confused as no single error log is displayed during the execution of the code, the screen just isn't reacting to any presses.

The inputForms work fine, I can write my email and password, but after pressing Login, or Forgot Password or switching between Create Account & Login, nothing happens.

I tried to find which libraries are  incompatible together, but didn't find any info.. I'm totally lost here.. Anyone ever experienced the same issue?

```
EXPO & REACT :
"expo": "~49.0.15",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.6"
CODE For login Screen: 
// LoginScreen.js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";

import { colors } from "../../infrastructure/theme/colors";
import * as S from "./components/account.styles";
import { AuthenticationContext } from "../../services/auth/authentication.context";

export const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState("Login");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const { onLogin, isLoading, error, setError } = useContext(
    AuthenticationContext
  );
  const handleTabPress = (tab) => {
    setSelectedTab("Login");
    console.log("here");
    navigation.navigate(tab);
  };

  // Clean-up error after refresh
  useEffect(() => {
    setError("");
  }, []);

  const isFormFilled = email !== "" && password !== "";

  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
      <S.Container>
        <S.Header>
          <S.TabContainer>
            <S.TabButton
              style={[S.TabButton, selectedTab === "Register" && S.SelectedTab]}
              onPress={() => handleTabPress("Register")}
            >
              <S.UnselectedTabText>Create Account</S.UnselectedTabText>
            </S.TabButton>
            <S.TabButton
              style={[S.TabButton, selectedTab === "Login" && S.SelectedTab]}
            >
              <S.TabText>Login</S.TabText>
              <S.SelectedTab></S.SelectedTab>
            </S.TabButton>
          </S.TabContainer>
        </S.Header>

        <S.FormContainer>
          <S.FormText>Email address</S.FormText>
          <S.Input
            placeholder="Eg namaemail@emailkamu.comil"
            placeholderTextColor="#CCCCCC"
            onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
            textContentType="emailAddress"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            inputMode="email"
          />

          <S.FormText>Password</S.FormText>
          <S.Input
            placeholder="**** **** ****"
            placeholderTextColor="#CCCCCC"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
          />

          <S.ForgotPasswordButton>
            <S.ForgotPasswordText onPress={() => console.log("hello")}>
              Forgot Password?
            </S.ForgotPasswordText>
          </S.ForgotPasswordButton>

          <S.ErrorContainer>
            <S.ErrorText>{error}</S.ErrorText>
          </S.ErrorContainer>
          <S.ButtonContainer>
            {!isLoading ? (
              <S.AuthButton
                style={[
                  S.LoginButton,
                  isFormFilled && { backgroundColor: colors.brand.secondary },
                ]}
                onPress={() => onLogin(email, password)}
              >
                <S.ButtonText
                  style={[!isFormFilled && { color: colors.process.button }]}
                >
                  Login
                </S.ButtonText>
              </S.AuthButton>
            ) : (
              <ActivityIndicator color={colors.brand.secondary} />
            )}
            <S.ButtonSeparator />

            <S.GoogleButton>
              <FontAwesome
                name="google"
                size={24}
                color="white"
                style={{ marginRight: 10 }}
              />
              <S.GoogleButtonText>Login with Google</S.GoogleButtonText>
            </S.GoogleButton>
          </S.ButtonContainer>
        </S.FormContainer>
      </S.Container>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

Navigation : // Modified AccountNavigator.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  CardStyleInterpolators,
  TransitionPresets,
} from "@react-navigation/stack";

import { LoginScreen } from "../../screens/account/login.screen";
import { RegisterScreen } from "../../screens/account/register.screen";
import { ResetPasswordScreen } from "../../screens/account/reset-password.screen";
import { ResetPasswordSuccessScreen } from "../../screens/account/reset-password-success.screen";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export const AuthNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Login"
      screenOptions={{ ...TransitionPresets.RevealFromBottomAndroid }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Register"
        component={RegisterScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Reset"
        component={ResetPasswordScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ResetSuccess"
        component={ResetPasswordSuccessScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};


Screen that displays my custom modal with register/login screens :
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Image, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Text } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-paper";

import { CustomModal } from "../../components/modal.component";
import { AuthNavigator } from "../../infrastructure/navigation/auth.navigator";
import { colors } from "../../infrastructure/theme/colors";
import { useTheme } from "../../services/theme/theme.context";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
const lightContainer = {
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
};

const darkContainer = {
  backgroundColor: "#222",
};

const lightThemeText = {
  color: "#222",
};

const darkThemeText = {
  color: "#fff",
};

export const AccountScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  // Theme
  // const { containerStyle, textStyle, colorScheme } = useTheme();
  const colorScheme = "light";

  // Modal
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
  };

  const onboardingImage =
    colorScheme === "light"
      ? require("../../../assets/onboarding-light.png")
      : require("../../../assets/onboarding-dark.png");

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, lightContainer]}>
      <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={onboardingImage} />
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.captionStyle}>
        Waffles are just pancakes with abs
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.descriptionStyle,
          // { color: colorScheme === "light" ? "black" : "white" },
        ]}
      >
        Our recipes and workouts are the perfect way to start your day. Sweat
        hard, then have a snack or drink. Whatever you prefer!
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          title="Show modal"
          mode="outlined"
          // textColor={colorScheme === "light" ? "black" : "white"}
          onPress={toggleModal}
        >
          Get Started
        </Button>
        <CustomModal
          visible={modalVisible}
          toggleModal={toggleModal}
          children={() => <AuthNavigator />}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  imageContainer: {
    width: width,
    height: "65%",
  },
  image: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    overflow: "visible",
  },
  captionStyle: {
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: "center",
    padding: 10,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: colors.brand.secondary,
  },
  descriptionStyle: {
    textAlign: "center",
    paddingTop: 10,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

Custom modal : 
import React from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, Modal } from "react-native";
import {
  ModalContainer,
  ModalContent,
  DragLineContainer,
  DragLine,
  DragTouchableOpacity,
} from "./modal.styles";

export const CustomModal = ({ visible, toggleModal, children }) => (
  <Modal visible={visible} transparent={true} animationType="slide">
    <ModalContainer>
      <ModalContent>
        <DragTouchableOpacity onPress={toggleModal} />
        <DragLineContainer>
          <DragLine />
        </DragLineContainer>
        {children()}
      </ModalContent>
    </ModalContainer>
  </Modal>
);
```

Comment: Did you check with element inspector (https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/tools/#showhide-element-inspector) if the current screen is obscured by an transparent view?

Comment: Yes I did and I solved it actually. The issue was, that I used styled lib for my components, and was using TouchableOpacity from styled lib. The issue was solved when I used TouchableOpacity from react native gesture handler

Comment: No, you should not add "Solved" to the title. Instead, if you have a solution, add it as an answer and then accept it. Edits adding "Solved" should likely be rolled back. @GregFenton Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum, but a Q/A site. It has a Question (Q) section, that's the one were you ask your Q. 
And it has an answer (A) section were other users (or yourself) can answer your Q.
See [**Can I answer my own question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, that I used styled lib for my components, and was using TouchableOpacity from styled lib. The issue was solved when I used TouchableOpacity from react native gesture handler